# Префикс к имени файла при сохранении

Tags: delphi

Как сделать, чтобы при сохранении файла программа добавляла префикс `New_`?

В моем случае получается на выходе: `Test.txt.txt`.
А нужно, чтобы получилось: `New_Test.txt`

```
LDstFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName + '.txt', fmCreate);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А-а-а, кажется понял, что Вам надо.

```
LDstFile := TFileStream.Create(
  ExtractFilePath(AFileName) + 'New_' + ExtractFileName(AFileName), fmCreate);
```

Comment: Igor, Как всегда Вы просто молодец и Человек с большой буквы. Прямо в точку, помогли. Очень Вам благодарна.