# Как сгенерировать случайное имя для файла?

Tags: delphi, файлы

Моя программа делает разные действия и после сохраняет результат в файл `rez.txt`. Как сделать, чтобы при сохранении, к имени файла присваивалась рандомная приставка или цифры по порядку?

То есть вместо `rez.txt`, нужно чтобы сохранялось как: `Генерируется_разное_имя_rez.txt`. Другими словами `New1__rez.txt`, `New2__rez.txt` и так далее...

```
var
  ft2: TextFile;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    AssignFile(ft2, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\rez.txt'); // <--
end;
```

Comment: Как сформировать префикс вам уже ответили в соседнем вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803772 Неужели вы не можете теперь догадаться и взять глобальный счётчик и добавить `IntToStr(MyCount)` к префиксу?

Comment: Да, я знаю и полностью согласна. Но как сделать так что бы он генерировал рандомное (произвольное) имя к файлу.

Comment: Может это и смешно но пока что не могу. Воспринимайте меня с позитивной стороны :).

Comment: Вроде так var i : Integer; // счетчик i = 0; i = i+1; // где то выше вашего кода // AssignFile(ft2,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+"\New"+IntToStr(i)+'_rez.txt');

Comment: Есть функция [Random](http://www.delphibasics.ru/random.php) если счётчик не устраивает.

Comment: Random(100);    // Эти 100 значений дают диапазон 0..99

Comment: Так выдает ошибку, точнее подчеркивает что ошибка в символе "\New"

Comment: string:=string+chr(random(26)+97); // зациклить несколько раз

Comment: Нужно использовать апостроф вместо двойной кавычки.

Comment: http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=228360 с этим можете попробовать

Comment: Использовала апостроф и теперь выделяет ошибку  i = 0;

Comment: там знак пропущен надо i:=0 // это я по привычке из другого языка написал

Comment: Заработало. А как сделать что бы если имя существует то генерировать новое. Именно в этом коде ? Он просто небольшой и удобный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function MakeNewName(OldName: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  path, ext: string;
begin
  path := ExtractFilePath(OldName); // извлекаем путь до файла
  ext := ExtractFileExt(OldName);  // извлекаем расширение файла
  i := 1;
  Result := path + 'Rez_' + IntToStr(i) + ext;  // формируем имя нового файла
  while FileExists(Result) do // если файл с таким именем существует, то формируем новое
  begin
    Inc(i);
    Result := path + 'Rez_' + IntToStr(i) + ext;
  end;
end;

...
AssignFile(ft2, MakeNewName(OpenDialog1.FileName));
...
```

Без функции:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  path, ext, new_name: string; 
...
if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
  AssignFile(ft, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(ft);
  path := ExtractFilePath(OldName); // извлекаем путь до файла
  ext := ExtractFileExt(OldName);  // извлекаем расширение файла
  i := 1;
  new_name := path + 'Rez_' + IntToStr(i) + ext;  // формируем имя нового файла
  while FileExists(new_name) do // если файл с таким именем существует, то формируем новое
  begin
    Inc(i);
    new_name := path + 'Rez_' + IntToStr(i) + ext;
  end;
  AssignFile(ft2, new_name);
  Rewrite(ft2); // чтобы создался новый, если нету, или перезаписался с нуля
  Append(ft2);
...
```

Comment: Result почему то выделяет как ошибку ?

Comment: @Татьяна в каком месте? Вы используете целиком функцию MakeNewName или пытаетесь её часть вставить в свой код?

Comment: Пытаюсь в код вставить. Если Вас не затруднит то помогите в мой код вставить. Код я выше только предоставила.

Comment: Подправил ответ для Вашего случая.

Comment: Спасибо работает. И последний вопрос: А как что бы в разширении .txt сохранялось сделать.

Comment: @Татьяна `new_name := path + 'Rez_' + IntToStr(i) + '.txt';`

Comment: Вот вы меня выручили. ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ Вам спасибо. Все превосходно работает. Премного, много благодарна.