# Как сохранять каждый новый файл с порядковым номером?

Tags: delphi

Как исправить код, чтобы программа сохраняла каждый новый файл с порядковым номером.

Сейчас сохраняет файл: `New_f`, `New_New_f`, `New_New_New_f` ..

А нужно что бы сохраняла: `New_f1`, `New_f2`, `New_f3` и так далее...

```
newName := ExtractFilePath(AFileName) + 'New_' + ExtractFileName(AFileName);
```

Comment: Укажите, какое имя у Вас изначально и какие Вы хотите получить? Вместе с расширениями

Comment: Изначально fayl. А получить fayl1, fayl2, fayl3 и так далее. То есть если такой файл существует то создается новый.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сгенерировать случайное имя для файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804477/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: А как именно в этом коде ? Опыта в этом нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя файла создаётся у вас строкой:

```
ExtractFilePath(AFileName) + 'New_' + ExtractFileName(AFileName)
```

Разумеется, каждый раз вы прибавляете к имени файла "New_" пр вызове данной процедуры. Чтобы избежать этого, есть варианты, например, простейший:

```
var
  filenumber:integer;

<...>

filenumber:=1;
<...>

procedure WriteLines(AIndices: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>; const AFileName: string);

begin
<...>
     LDstFile := TFileStream.Create(
        ExtractFilePath(AFileName) + 'New_f' + IntToStr(filenumber)+'.txt', fmCreate); // при условии, что расширение у файла = '.txt'
     inc(filenumber);
<...>
end;
```

Но, если хочется, чтобы номер определялся непосредственно из имени файла, то, к примеру так:

```
procedure WriteLines(AIndices: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>; const AFileName: string);
var
  tmp1,tmp2:string;
  i:integer;
begin
<...>
   tmp1:=Delete(ExtractFileName(AFileName),1,5);// поскольку мы знаем префикс файла 'New_f'
   tmp2:='';
   i:=1;
   while tmp1[i] in ['0' .. '9'] do  // выделяем числовую составляющую файла
      begin
         tmp2:=tmp2+tmp1[i];
         inc(i);
      end;
   tmp1:=Copy(tmp1,i,length(tmp1)-i+1); // запоминаем оставшуюся часть файла вместе с расширением
   i:=StrToInt(tmp2);
   inc(i); // увеличиваем число на 1
   tmp2:=ExtractFilePath(AFileName)+'New_f'+IntToStr(i)+tmp1; // новое имя файла
<...>
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо получилось. Вопрос решен.